# Wiring two Gradle tasks together via a property

Tags: gradle

#### The question:

In Gradle, how do I make the output of one task be a property and the input of another task be that same property? Especially in the context of that property being needed at configuration time.

#### What I'm trying to accomplish:

I'm attempting to write a `Tar` task that depends on user input. I'm having trouble with the need for lazy configuration given that the "baseName" is not known at configuration time.

#### Code

Here's what I would like to work but it doesn't.

```
task saveDb(type: Tar, dependsOn: getTarBaseName) {
    // Next line doesn't work but does if I surround 2nd param with '{}'
    inputs.property("baseName", getTarBaseName.baseName) // Doesn't work

    from file("$dbsDir/data")
    destinationDir = file(project.dbsBackupDir)
    baseName = getTarBaseName.baseName // Doesn't work
    extension = 'tar'
    compression = Compression.NONE
}

task getTarBaseName() {
    doFirst {
        def result = BuildUtil.promptForName() // Uses Swing to prompt for a name
        getTarBaseName.ext.baseName = result
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm using `ext` to try to pass information between tasks, but that is just incidental not a requirement. Also I'm using 2 tasks, I'm completely willing to use only 1, however, that wouldn't really answer the general question which is one I hit against fairly often when attempting to use Gradle as a cross platform bash replacement for project related tasks.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your specific problem (if I did not miss something), you don't need a second task. Just add a `doFirst` closure to your `Tar` task and set the `baseName` property there to whatever you want:

```
task saveDb(type: Tar) {
    // static configuration
    doFirst {
        baseName = BuildUtil.promptForName()
        // or for another task (don't forget to depend on that task)
        baseName = otherTask.myProperty
    }
}

task otherTask {
    doFirst {
        ext.myProperty = BuildUtil.promptForName()
    }
}
```

---

However, your question boils down a general difficulty in Gradle: **when** to apply a specific piece of configuration.

Gradle just introduced a rather [new feature for lazy configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html): `Provider` and `Property`

> Gradle provides lazy properties, which delay the calculation of a property’s value until it’s absolutely required.

Before Gradle 4.0, only files could be lazy evaluated (via [`ConfigurableFileCollection`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/ConfigurableFileCollection.html)), as an example:

```
task myZip(type: Zip) {
    // zip some files
}

task copyMyZip(type: Copy) {
    from myZip
}

myZip.baseName = 'myZip'
```

Even if the name of the zip file is defined **after** the `Zip` task is added to the `Copy` task configuration, its correct path will be used for the copy operation.

Now, with Gradle 4.0 and up, all configuration parameters that implement `Property` or `Provider` can be bound easily (check out the link above) and you can also lazily read a configuration parameter by wrapping it into a `Provider`, but it's difficult to put a provider value into an old configuration parameter. You still need to specify the moment **when** to evaluate (inside the task action, in a `doFirst` closure or an `afterEvaluate` handler). This problem is the topic of [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4224).